# How to Open a Web Server from Running an Executable?

Tags: racket

I've been toying with the idea of using my browser as a GUI instead of using the GUI package provided by Racket.

The code is as follows:

```
#lang racket

(require web-server/servlet web-server/servlet-env)

(define (start req) (response/xexpr "Goodbye, World!"))

(serve/servlet start #:port 8080 #:servlet-path "/")
```

When I run this in the IDE, it works just fine. But when I try running this from an executable, it just runs and doesn't open a browser window. How do I get this program working in executable form?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  There was a problem with the machine I was running it on.  My program runs on all other systems just fine.